# Remove "overflow: hidden" inline style on Fancybox container on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fancybox, fancybox-3

how do I remove `overflow:hidden;` inline style from the fancybox-content div? I'm using FancyBox 3.5.7. It seems Wordpress is overriding the code. Before coding for WordPress, the inline style was `display: inline-block;`. Now that I imported the code to Wordpress, it has been added `overflow: hidden;` when I intended not to. Would appreciate the help in advance, thanks guys.

How do I remove the additional `overflow: hidden;` inline style from the fancybox-content div. Working on Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

you can add your customized CSS and use 
overflow: '(your attribute)' !Important.

!Important is specifying that what property will be affected.
or use inline overflow:none to disable it